# Deadlock in concurrent.futures code

Tags: python, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I've been trying to parallelise some code using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` but have kept having strange deadlocks that don't occur with `ThreadPoolExecutor`.  A minimal example:

```
from concurrent import futures

def test():
    pass

with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(4) as executor:
    for i in range(100):
        print('submitting {}'.format(i))
        executor.submit(test)
```

In python 3.2.2 (on 64-bit Ubuntu), this seems to hang consistently after submitting all the jobs - and this seems to happen whenever the number of jobs submitted is greater than the number of workers.  If I replace `ProcessPoolExecutor` with `ThreadPoolExecutor` it works flawlessly.

As an attempt to investigate, I gave each future a callback to print the value of `i`:

```
from concurrent import futures

def test():
    pass

with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(4) as executor:
    for i in range(100):
        print('submitting {}'.format(i))
        future = executor.submit(test)

        def callback(f):
            print('callback {}'.format(i))
        future.add_done_callback(callback)
```

This just confused me even more - the value of `i` printed out by `callback` is the value at the time it is called, rather than at the time it was defined (so I never see `callback 0` but I get lots of `callback 99`s).  Again, `ThreadPoolExecutor` prints out the expected value.

Wondering if this might be a bug, I tried a recent development version of python.  Now, the code at least seems to terminate, but I still get the wrong value of `i` printed out.

So can anyone explain:

- what happened to `ProcessPoolExecutor` in between python 3.2 and the current dev version that apparently fixed this deadlock
- why the 'wrong' value of `i` is being printed

EDIT: as jukiewicz pointed out below, of course printing `i` will print the value at the time the callback is called, I don't know what I was thinking... if I pass a callable object with the value of `i` as one of its attributes, that works as expected.

EDIT: a little bit more information: all of the callbacks are executed, so it looks like it is `executor.shutdown` (called by `executor.__exit__`) that is unable to tell that the processes have completed.  This does seem to be completely fixed in the current python 3.3, but there seem to have been a lot of changes to `multiprocessing` and `concurrent.futures`, so I don't know what fixed this.  Since I can't use 3.3 (it doesn't seem to be compatible with either the release or dev versions of numpy), I tried simply copying its multiprocessing and concurrent packages across to my 3.2 installation, which seems to work fine.  Still, it seems a little weird that - as far as I can see - `ProcessPoolExecutor` is completely broken in the latest release version but nobody else is affected.

Comment: As to the second one, it's natural that processes print `99`. symbol `i` is bound by the global context, and creating new processes is costly, so by the time you get to executing anything, `i == 99`.

Comment: Also, I have Ubuntu 64-bit, Python 3.2.2 and the first code snippet doesn't hang...

Comment: @julkiewicz: that's very strange.  I have just tried it on a different machine running 64-bit Scientific Linux and python 3.2.2, and it stalled after printing 'submitting 99' on 10 tries out of 10.  I even tried wrapping the code in `if __name__ == '__main__'` as I've heard that is necessary for multiprocessing on Windows.

Comment: Actually, I can't see a pattern in the numbers of jobs and workers required for this to happen.  For example, 1 worker and 2 jobs is OK, 1 worker and 3 jobs hangs, 8 workers and 16 jobs hangs about half the time.

Answer (score 3):

I modified the code as follows, that solved both problems. `callback` function was defined as a closure, thus would use the updated value of `i` every time. As for deadlock, that's likely to be a cause of shutting down the Executor before all the task are complete. Waiting for the futures to complete solves that, too.

```
from concurrent import futures

def test(i):
    return i

def callback(f):
    print('callback {}'.format(f.result()))


with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(4) as executor:
    fs = []
    for i in range(100):
        print('submitting {}'.format(i))
        future = executor.submit(test, i)
        future.add_done_callback(callback)
        fs.append(future)

    for _ in futures.as_completed(fs): pass
```

UPDATE: oh, sorry, I haven't read your updates, this seems have been solved already.